# Steps to sync to Google Tasks API

Tags: android, google-tasks-api

I am making a To do list android app. I want to sync the tasks to Google Tasks.

I am using Google API client libraries for Java. I have implemented all the authentication process as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android).

But i am somewhat confused on what steps to take to sync the tasks. Like, should i have to compare each and every list and tasks if they are changed or not.

Also, the task ids in Google tasks are of the type string. If i want to change a particular task, how will i know the id?

Please Help!!